# How do i prevent math.random form selecting the same value twice

Tags: javascript

```js
var navne = ["peter", "mads", "Per"]

var randomNavn = navne[Math.floor(Math.random() * navne.length)];

var spørgsmål = [`bund din drink ${randomNavn}`, `tag 2 shots ${randomNavn}`, `del 2 tåre ud ${randomNavn}`]


var randomItem = spørgsmål[Math.floor(Math.random() * spørgsmål.length)];


function næsteSpørgsmål() {

  if (!spørgsmål.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      spørgsmål.push(i);
    }

    var val = spørgsmål[index]

    randomItem.splice(randomItem, 1);

    console.log(randomItem)
    return val;
  }
}

console.log(næsteSpørgsmål());
```

Comment: if you prevent it from sketching the same value twice then it wouldn't be very random. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to achieve this, is to remove the selected element from the array.

```
// generate random index
let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * spørgsmål.length)
// get item at the generated index
let randomItem = spørgsmål[randomIndex]
// remove item from array, so it can't be selected again
spørgsmål.splice(randomIndex, 1)
```